# How to manage dates in Custom Validations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello Devs I'm trying to compare dates in a custom validator, but it seems that i'm not doing it properly.

i need to make a condition for a document, if 90 days have passed since the date of expiration, if its true then return an error.

```
class CheckDocumentValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
    def validate(record)
        
        expiration_date = record.expiration_date
        actual_date = Time.current

        diff = ((actual_date - expiration_date.to_time)/3600).round

        days_diff = diff/24

        if days_diff > 90
           record.errors.add(:expiration_date, "error")
        end
    end
end
```

expiration_date is a date attribute on my model AttachmentInstance

In the logs says that -- Error: undefined method `to_time' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the error

```ruby
Error: undefined method `to_time' for nil:NilClass
```

is because no data found on `record.expiration_date`.

if `record.expiration_date` is `Time` class. it should be like this

```ruby
if record.expiration_date + 90.day > Time.now
 record.errors.add(:expiration_date, "error")
end
```